# How do I use compiled Kotlin code in a JS app?

Tags: javascript, kotlin, electron, kotlin-multiplatform, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm having some trouble compiling some Kotlin code into JS and using it in an Electron app. The project is a minimal fork of jpd236's kotwords library.

I added the `@JsExport` decorator to a function and then tried compiling it using a couple methods.

The first thing I tired was `gradlew jsNodeProductionRun`.
That created the directory `build/js/packages/kotwords`.

Inside `build/js/packages/kotwords/kotlin`, among lots of other files there is a `kotwords.js`, `kotwords.js.map`, and `kotwords.d.ts`. Looking at the type definitions file, my function was exported correctly. I tried dumping the whole build directory into my Electron project but when I tried to import the compiled code using:

```
import * as kotwords from '../../build/js/packages/kotwords/kotlin/kotwords';
```

But I get the error:

```
Cannot find module './kotlin-kotlin-stdlib-js-ir.js'
```

That file definitely exists in the same directory as kotwords.js. I looked in kotwords.js and saw this line:

```
  throw new Error("Error loading module 'kotwords'. Its dependency 'kotlin-kotlin-stdlib-js-ir' was not found. Please, check whether 'kotlin-kotlin-stdlib-js-ir' is loaded prior to 'kotwords'.");
```

Based on that, I tried importing that file with an import statement before importing * as kotowrds but that did not help.

So then the next thing I tried was bundling it using webpack by running

```
gradlew jsBrowserDevelopmentWebpack
```

This created a single `kotwords.js` file in `build/developmentExecutable`.
I added that file to my electron app but it didn't seem to be exporting my function anymore.
I ran the following code:

```
import * as kotwords from './kotwords';
console.log(kotwords);
```

And it returned: `Module {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Module'}`
which was an emtpy object.

Any ideas what else I can try?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Did you tried https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-ir-compiler.html

Comment: I wrote a series of Kotlin/JS article. Take a look if they help. They cover exactly what you're trying to look for
https://dev.to/shaktiman_droid/series/17147

Comment: Vahid, yep I did look through the docs and they weren't helpful.

Comment: shaltiman_droid I had seen Part I and Part II but somehow missed Part III which was exactly what I needed! I finally was able to get it working. I think my problem was I hadn't included "output.library" in my gradle task. Great articles btw!